# Django webpage with offline manager

Tags: java, python, ajax, django

I'd like to create a Django webpage, and an offline "manager" program for it.

For example a weblog with an offline editor for PCs (I'd prefer Java), but I'd like to store the entries both offline and online. And create the offline "manager" for it, and provide online admin page for it. When i modify something in the offline program, I can send an AJAX (or something like AJAX) message to the site. But I'd like to create push-notifications in my offline app, to notify the offline user, if I modify something on the online admin page.

What's the best way to do it securely?

I did run itno Websockets, but Django do not support websockets. The "from offline to online" way can be implemented somehow with AJAX, or something similar. How to do this securely? And the "from online to offline". If it's possible, I'd like to avoid the "ask the server for changes in every 5 minutes" way.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want an offline manager or a native (desktop) manager? Offline means not connected to Internet and in that case you will need to store stuff locally and then sync whenever the manager goes offline.

Comment: I'd like an offline manager. The locally storing is not a big deal, I'd like to create a lot of stuff, which will only locally stored. For example notes to the post, ideas, and so on.  
  And there will be a lot of stuff just for online: for example user's data (email), stats, so on.  
  The main question is, how to implement the secure, and cool synchronization between the offline app, and the webpage. I can make the "synchronize-everything-since-the-last-time" stuff, but I don't know what's the best method to make this sync secure, and cool. (eg.: push notifications instead of polling)

Comment: For an "native" manager you can use REST API for communication. For push notifications. you can try one of these https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/websockets/

Comment: Seems like you are at an early stage and you first need to draw your architecture clearly before jumping into "cool" stuff like django or websockets. Its too early to be on SO as of now.

Comment: Yep, you see it right, I'm at an very early stage.  
  I know, that I want a weblog system, with an offline manager. I'd like to write the weblog system in Django, 'cause that's what I know a little. And I want to create an offline manager for it.  
  I think, I could design, and write just a weblog system. I think, I could design, and write an offline app.  
  But I haven't got the smallest idea to implement the sync between them. And I want to know, how to create the sync, before I write one line of code...